# Laravel 5 Eloquent query for haversine formula

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this query

```
select tbl_container.*, 
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(17.7427643) ) 
              * cos( radians( tbl_locations.latitude ) ) 
              * cos( radians( tbl_locations.longitude ) - radians(83.3277787) ) 
              + sin( radians(17.7427643) ) 
              * sin( radians( tbl_locations.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
from tbl_locations,tbl_container  
where tbl_container.`status` = 1 
and tbl_container.location_id=tbl_locations.id having distance<4 order by distance asc
```

For this i have two models Containers,Locations

how to write this query to laravel 5 eloquent...

Answer (score 0):

I did't get any eloquent model query for this
so am using query like this

```
DB::select(DB::raw(' select tbl_container.*, 
      ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(17.7427643) ) 
             * cos( radians( tbl_locations.latitude ) ) 
             * cos( radians( tbl_locations.longitude ) - radians(83.3277787) ) 
             + sin( radians(17.7427643) ) 
             * sin( radians( tbl_locations.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
from tbl_locations,tbl_container  
where tbl_container.`status` = 1 
and tbl_container.location_id=tbl_locations.id having distance<4 order by distance asc   '));
```

and using this DB facade for this raw query

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```